# Python threading/subprocess; thread object invalid when subprocess is still running

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm writing some monitoring tools and one such tool processes a list of NFS-mounted filesystems and attempts to write a test file to each share. I spawn a thread for each filer being tested. After a certain timeout, I want to terminate any threads that are still running. I don't need to gather output from the threads, I don't need to join or connect to any of the threads, I just need to stop any that are still running after my timeout.

So I intentionally run a sleep(300) in each thread, so I know w/o question the process spawned in each thread is still running at the end when I loop thru all the active threads and try killing them. This works for anywhere from 5-20 threads but then eventually fails on a thread saying self.pid is no longer valid. The thread this happens on is random and not necessarily the same thread as the last run.

```
class NFSWriteTestThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, filer, base_mnt_point, number):
        super(NFSWriteTestThread, self).__init__()
        self.tname    = filer
        self.tnum     = number
        self.filer    = filer
        self.mntpt    = base_mnt_point
        self.process  = None
        self.pid      = None

    def run(self):
        start = time.time()
#        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/dd', 'if=/dev/zero', 'bs=1M', 'count=5', 'of=' + self.testfile], shell=False)
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sleep', '300'], shell=False)
        time.sleep(1)
        logger.debug("DEBUG: %s=%d" % (self.tname, self.process.pid))
        self.pid     = self.process.pid
        logger.info("  NFS write test command initiaited on '%s', pid=%d" % (self.filer, self.pid))
        self.process.wait()
#        self.output, self.error = self.process.communicate()
        end = time.time()
        logger.info("  NFS write test for '%s' completed in %d seconds" % (self.filer, end - start))
        return

    def getThreadName(self):
        return self.tname

    def getThreadNum(self):
        return self.tnum

    def getThreadPID(self):
        if self.pid:
            return self.pid
        else:
            return "unknown"

    def isAlive(self):
        if not self.process:
            logger.debug("Error: self.process is invalid (%s)" % type(self.process))
#        if self.process.poll():
#            logger.info("NFS write test operation for thread '%s' is still active" % self.filer)
#        else:
#            logger.info("NFS write test operation for thread '%s' is inactive" % self.filer)
        return

    def terminate(self):
        os.kill(self.process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
        return

    def kill(self):
        os.kill(self.process.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
        return

def initLogging(config):

    logfile   = os.path.join(config['logdir'], config['logfilename'])
    fformat   = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s   %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
    cformat   = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s   %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
    clogger   = None
    flogger   = None

    if config['debug']:
        loglevel = logging.DEBUG

    if not os.path.exists(config['logdir']):
        os.makedirs(config['logdir'])
        os.chmod(config['logdir'], 0700)
        os.chown(config['logdir'], 0, 0)

    try:
        logger = logging.getLogger('main')
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # Define a file logger
        flogger = logging.FileHandler(logfile, 'w')
        flogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        flogger.setFormatter(fformat)
        logger.addHandler(flogger)

        # Define a console logger if verbose
        if config['verbose']:
            clogger = logging.StreamHandler()
            clogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            clogger.setFormatter(cformat)
            logger.addHandler(clogger)
    except Exception, error:
        print "Error: Unable to initialize file logging:  %s" % error
        sys.exit(1)

    logger.info("Script initiated.")

    logger.info("Using the following configuration:")
    for key, value in sorted(config.iteritems()):
        logger.info("    %20s = '%-s'" % (key, value))

    return logger

def parseConfigFile(cfg):

    if not os.path.isfile(cfg['cfgfile']) or not os.access(cfg['cfgfile'], os.R_OK):
        print "Error: '%s' does not exist or is not readable, terminating." % cfg['cfgfile']
        sys.exit(1)

    config = SafeConfigParser()
    config.read(cfg['cfgfile'])

    _cfg = dict(config.items(cfg['cfgfilestanza']))

    _cfgfilers = config.get(cfg['cfgfilestanza'], 'managed_filers')
    _tmpfilers = _cfgfilers.split(',')

    # populate a list containing all filers which will be meged into the global cfg[] dict
    _cfg['filers'] = []

    for _f in _tmpfilers:
        _cfg['filers'].append(_f.strip())

    return _cfg


logger = initLogging(cfg)
cfg.update(parseConfigFile(cfg))

threads     = []
numThreads  = 0

for filer in cfg['filers']:
    numThreads += 1
    logger.debug("  spawning NFS wite test thread for '%s', thread number %s" % (filer, numThreads))
    t = NFSWriteTestThread(filer, cfg['base_mnt_point'], numThreads)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
#    time.sleep(1)

logger.info("spawned %d NFS write test child threads" % numThreads)

logger.info("sleeping for %d seconds" % cfg['timeout'])
time.sleep(cfg['timeout'])

if (threading.activeCount() > 1):
    logger.info("there are %d NFS write test threads active after the timeout:" % (threading.activeCount() - 1))
    for thr in threading.enumerate():
        logger.debug("theadname=%s" % thr.name)
        if re.match("MainThread", thr.getName()):
            pass
        else:
            logger.info("thread '%s' (thread %d) is still alive" % (thr.getThreadName(), thr.getThreadNum()))
#            thr.isAlive()
            logger.info("killing thread for '%s' (pid=XX) with SIGTERM" % (thr.getThreadName()))
#            logger.info("killing thread for '%s' (pid=%d) with SIGTERM" % (thr.getThreadName(), thr.getThreadPID()))
            thr.kill()


logger.info("Script complete")
sys.exit(0)
```

Here you can see the output:

```
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   there are 173 NFS write test threads active after the timeout:
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   theadname=Thread-165
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   thread 'hostname1' (thread 165) is still alive
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   killing thread for 'hostname1' (pid=XX) with SIGTERM
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   theadname=Thread-97
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   thread 'hostname2' (thread 97) is still alive
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST     NFS write test for 'hostname1' completed in 60 seconds
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   killing thread for 'hostname2' (pid=XX) with SIGTERM
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   theadname=Thread-66
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   thread 'hostname3' (thread 66) is still alive
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST     NFS write test for 'hostname2' completed in 60 seconds
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   killing thread for 'hostname3' (pid=XX) with SIGTERM
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   theadname=Thread-121
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   thread 'hostname4' (thread 121) is still alive
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST   killing thread for 'hostname4' (pid=XX) with SIGTERM
Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-11-10 09:00:22 CST     NFS write test for 'hostname3' completed in 60 seconds
  File "./NFSWriteTestCheck.py", line 199, in <module>
    thr.kill()
  File "./NFSWriteTestCheck.py", line 84, in kill
    os.kill(self.process.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
```

At the point this error is displayed the process is still running, verified with ps in a shell. Why is the thread object no longer valid? At the point this error is thrown, the thread execution should be at this point:

self.process.wait()

Just scratching my head here, wondering if I'm hitting a bug or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop threads, you can only interrupt the things that they are doing. In your case, the thread is waiting on `subprocess.call`. Setting an event has no effect because your thread doesn't wait on the event. The solution here is to kill the child process which means that you'll need the Popen object.

I put the implementation directly into the run method so that the Popen object is handy.

```
class NFSWriteTestThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, filer, mntpoint, number):
        super(NFSWriteTestThread, self).__init__()
        self.name   = filer
        self.filer  = filer
        self.mntpt  = mntpoint
        self.tnum   = number
        self._proc  = None

    def run(self):
        testfile = "%s/%s/test/test.%s" % (mountpoint, filer, filer)
        testcmd  = "/bin/bash -c '/bin/dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1024 of=" + testfile + " >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; sleep 120'"
        self._proc = subprocess.Popen(testcmd, shell=True)
        self._proc.wait()
        return

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def kill(self):
        if self._proc:
            self._proc.terminate()

    def stopped(self):
        if self._proc:
            return self._proc.poll() is not None
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: I was trying that approach as one point and it kept complaining saying "AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'terminate'". I'll update my original code to show my current version.

Comment: `terminate` is new to python 2.6. It should also be in 2.7. If you are using redhat 5 for instance, the default python is 2.4 and its not there. `terminate` is just a way to make linux and windows work the same, you can  `import signal`, and then `self._proc.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)`

Comment: I'm having a hell of a time with this. I gave up trying to terminate() and kill() and am now using os.kill which works.. However, when evaluating process.pid I get inconsistent results.. At a time when I know 100% the process is still running, verified with ps and the fact that the thread is now running a sleep(300), however, sporadically self.pid is getting unset somehow even though the process is still running.